# Flex Wrapping css wrapping the entire row down

Tags: html, css

I have the following scenario in my website:

[image]

To explain, I have 3 columns, and every cell is going to have a different height, and I would like to wrap it so that it doesn't wrap the entire row, but rather it wraps and positions the elements properly like this:

[image]

My current css settings:

```css
.article {
    flex-basis: 33.333%;
    align-self: flex-start;
    padding: 10px;    
    border:1px solid green;
    white-space: nowrap
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.f-wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Snippet of the HTML code:

```html
<div class="b-section flex f-wrap v-margin-2">
    <div class="article"></div>
    <div class="article"></div>
    <div class="article" style="height: 200px"></div>
    <div class="article"></div>
    <div class="article"></div>
    <div class="article"></div>
    <div class="article"></div>
    <div class="article"></div>          
</div>
```

I've also tried with display grid, but I'm still getting this:

[image]

```css
.articles {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.article {
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-section articles grid v-margin-2">
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article" style="height: 200px"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps look at grid, in particular the [grid-auto-flow: dense](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/grid-auto-flow/) property?

Comment: I've looked at some examples, but in all of them they're setting the height manually of every cell. In My case the height of every element will be detrmined by the cell contents which will be an image taken from database

Comment: I think you're probably looking at something like masonry layout. I think firefox does it out of the box but the reality is you're looking at a third-party solution. There are a few out there that look pretty decent.

Comment: Yes exactly, can I achieve that with just flex display?

Comment: Also I've just tried your suggestion of using a grid display, I did and you can reload this page  I've edited the post to include also my attempt of  implementing it with a grid display, without success.